# How to check Google index count of a url or webpage link

Tags: google-search

In my project I need this result (Google index count) to be added as an
important information.

If you have any link from where I can get Google index  count of a url, it will be helpful to me.

Comment: There is no “Google index count”. You can only get the rank of a certain web page for a certain search query at a certain time.

Comment: it varies with location and with person's account

Answer (score 0):

**I know it late to answer this question but i got a gr8 php function to do that...**
since i stumbled on your question while searching for a solution
i want to share it with future searchers

**php Function:**

```
function getGoogleCount($domain) {
    $content = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/' .
        'search/web?v=1.0&filter=0&q=site:' . urlencode($domain));
    $data = json_decode($content);
    $result = intval($data->responseData->cursor->estimatedResultCount);

    if ($result > 1000) {
      $result = floor($result / 1000) . 'K';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Usage (in desired location):**

```
<?php echo getGoogleCount('http://www.example.com'); ?>
```

Hope this helps.
Sagive

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Google share all indexed pages and indexed links information to public. it only share few to public but share major information to verified web master in Google web-master tools.

Webmaster tools results can be displayed where ever you want.

You can check it via site:domain.com or site:url. there are few operators used by google
http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html.

Answer (score -1):

Please visit the following link:

http://www.wetware.co.nz/blog/2009/07/googles-index-count/